# How to add monochrome version of the Android adaptive app icon to Android Studio

Tags: android

I am trying to add themed adaptive icon to my existing Android application. I am following the steps explained here: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/icon_design_adaptive

However I am struggling with the part where I need to add the monochrome file to the ic_launcher.xml file:

```
 <monochrome android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_monochrome" />
```

How do I add the actual monochrome image to the project? I have created a black and white .png file but not to sure where to put it.